# Get current jupyter-lab notebook name [for Jupyter-lab version 2.1 and 3.0.1 and notebook version >6.0.3)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

#### Problem

Hi all,

As my title suggested it, I would like to get access to the notebook name (in **jupyter-lab**) as a variable. So I could reuse it in the notebook itself (for example to name some figure files generated in the notebook).

I saw that a similar issue was opened years ago [[see here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544056/how-do-i-get-the-current-ipython-jupyter-notebook-name). However I didnt find a satisfactory answer.

I like the simplicity of [the answer suggested by @bill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756989/13890678):

```py
import ipyparams
```

```py
currentNotebook = ipyparams.notebook_name
```

However, it doesn't work for me. I got this warning the first time I execute the first cell:

```py
import ipyparams
Javascript Error: Jupyter is not defined
```

```py
currentNotebook = ipyparams.notebook_name
```

```py
currentNotebook
   ''
```

Then if I rerun the cell again, I don't have the warning message anymore but the variable `currentNotebook` is still empty. (I run the cell sequentially, I didn't do a 'Run All Cells').

#### Configuration details

My Jupyter version is

```
jupyter notebook --version                                                                            
6.0.3]

jupyter-lab --version                                                                                 
2.1.1
```

I am using my notebook mostly for **python** code.

### Edit 27/01/2021

@juan solution [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65907473/13890678)], using [ipynbname](https://pypi.org/project/ipynbname/) is working for

```
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.6
jupyter lab : 2.2.6
```

<s>but this solution is still not working for `jupyter lab : 3.0.1`</s>

### Edit 28/01/2021

**[ipynbname](https://pypi.org/project/ipynbname/) is now working for jupyter 3**

More details about it [[here](https://github.com/msm1089/ipynbname/issues/2)]

Comment: Caveat: New issue opened at https://github.com/msm1089/ipynbname/issues/10 because for me it works with ipykernel but not with Xeus.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As an alternative you can use the following library: [ipynbname](https://pypi.org/project/ipynbname/)

```
#! pip install ipynbname

import ipynbname
nb_fname = ipynbname.name()
nb_path = ipynbname.path()
```

This worked for me and the solution is quite straightforward.

Comment: Thank you @Juan! Have you tried with `jupter-lab` too? In my case it only works with `jupyter-notebook`

Comment: When running it in `jupyter-lab`, I got the error `FileNotFoundError: Can't identify the notebook name`

Comment: Yes, I only tried it in jupyter lab. @Bill's solution doesn't work for me either, but this one does. `jupyter lab --version 2.2.6`  `conda --version 4.9.2`

Comment: Please take a look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687077/cant-run-any-ipynb-files-using-jupyter-lab-or-jupyter-notebook-filenotfounderr/52558580)

Comment: Thanks, I had a look I already have `nb_conda` install. By any chance do you have jupyterlab 3.0 install? maybe it works only for jupyter-lab <3.0

Comment: So I just tried with `jupyter lab --version 2.2.6` and it is working. The problem appears on jupyter-lab >3.0

Comment: Sure enough, I tried in jupyter lab 3.0.5 and it doesn't work. It seems to be then there is a problem with versions higher than 3

Comment: After opening an issue on the `ipynbname` repository , they added the compatibility for `jupyter >3` . See issue [[here](https://github.com/msm1089/ipynbname/issues/2#issuecomment-768879726)]

Comment: It worked fine for me with jupyter lab 3.1.2 provided I was using ipykernel; it did not work with Xeus kernel.

Comment: Confirming that works perfectly in `jupyter lab --version 3.3.2`

Comment: This work for me but extremely slow 20+ seconds, is it expected ?

Comment: This currently works in JupyterLab 4 and Jupyter Notebook 7+ running Python kernels. I was not finding it to work in JupyterLite, even after running `%pip install ipynbname jupyter_core`.

Comment: Great answer except for small quibble ... The commented out suggestion should be to install with `%pip install ipynbname`. . The magic install commands insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel running in the notebook. The exclamation point variation doesn't do this and was leading to issues that adding the magic variation was aimed at solving. The magic install commands had been added two years prior to this answer being posted

Answer (score -2):

You need to put the import code in a separate cell above the function (ipyparams.notebook_name). Otherwise it will try to run the code before the library is fully loaded, so the currentNotebook variable is still blank. Putting the import in its own cell forces it to load before moving to cell #2.

Comment: Thank you @mistertham. I tried but it doesn't solve the problem. I have edited my initial post in which I separate the import and the function call.

Answer (score -2):

For those lacking `ipynbname`, this JavaScript hack will work to grab the Jupyter notebook filename and path and save them to variables accessible by Python. However, you cannot access those variables in the same cell as you run the JavaScript code. So if you want to do anything with the variables, it'll take a second cell.

Proof-of-concept: A simple Jupyter notebook, `world.ipynb`, in directory `hello`.

Cell #1:

```py
def get_notebook_name():
    """Execute JS code to save Jupyter notebook name to variable `notebook_name`"""
    from IPython.core.display import Javascript, display_javascript
    js = Javascript("""IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('notebook_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"');""")
    return display_javascript(js)

def get_notebook_path():
    """Execute JS code to save Jupyter notebook path to variable `notebook_path`"""
    from IPython.core.display import Javascript, display_javascript
    js = Javascript("""IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('notebook_path = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_path + '"');""")
    return display_javascript(js)

# execute javascript
get_notebook_name()
get_notebook_path()
```

Cell #2

```py
# print results
print(f"{notebook_name=}")
print(f"{notebook_path=}")
```

Results:

```
notebook_name='world.ipynb'
notebook_path='hello/world.ipynb'
```

Comment: Says IPython is not defined in Jupyter Lab

Comment: Confirming these still do NOT work in `jupyter lab --version 3.3.2`